# Преобразование строки байтов в объект байты

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, byte

Я получаю байты из json которые записаны как строка

```
s = '\xd0\xbf\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82'
```

Как перевести строку в тип байты, чтобы было так

```
s = b'\xd0\xbf\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82'
```

Пробовал использовать encode но оно выдает не тот результат

```
s = '\xd0\xbf\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82'

print(s)

print(s.encode())
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Через получение числового кода каждого символа, потом преобразования набора этих кодов в байты:

```
s = '\xd0\xbf\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82'
b = bytes(map(ord, s))  # или b = bytes(ord(x) for x in s)
print(b)  # b'\xd0\xbf\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82'
```

Также работает такой вариант:

```
b = s.encode('latin1')
```

Answer (score 5):

```py
>>> s = '\xd0\xbf\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82'
>>> b = bytes(s, 'raw_unicode_escape')
>>> b
b'\xd0\xbf\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82'
>>> b[0]
208
```

Comment: Да, нужна была кодировка `raw_unicode_escape`